# How to put one TikZ picture on top of another?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I have two `TikZ` pictures on my slide, and now for me they are displayed one next to the other. I want first one to be on top of the other one. Also, I want to draw three arrows between Alice and Bob, but currently the text "`0` or `1`" in the arrow from Alice to Bob is not correctly placed, and I also want to draw one more arrow below it from Bob to Alice with text `$\sigma$`.

[image]

> How can I achieve these stuff?

```
    \documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
    
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        arrows,
        calc,
        chains,
        decorations,
        decorations.text,
        decorations.pathmorphing,
        matrix,
        positioning,
        shapes,
        tikzmark
    }
    \usepackage{tikzpeople}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}{Protocol View}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (e0) at (0,0) {$E_0$};
        \node (epk) at (6,0) {$E_{pk}$};
        \path[->] (e0) edge node[auto]{$\mathfrak{s}$} (epk);
        \uncover<2->{
          \node (er) at (3,3) {$E_r$};
          \path[->] (e0) edge node[auto]{$\mathfrak{r}$} (er);
        }
        \uncover<4->{
          \path[dashed,->] (epk) edge node[auto,swap]{$\mathfrak{r}\cdot\mathfrak{s}^{-1}$} (er);
          \node (b0) at (0,3) {$b = 0$};
          \node (b1) at (6,3) {$b = 1$};
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm]
            % nodes
            \node[alice,minimum size=1cm,] (s) at (0,0) {Alice};
            \node[bob,minimum size=1cm,right of=s] (r) {Bob};
            % paths
            \draw [->,visible on=<2->] (r) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center] {$E_r$} (s);
            \draw [->,visible on=<4->] ($(s.east)+(1em,-1em)$) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,align=center] {$0$ or $1$} ($(r.west)+(-1em,-1em)$);
            %\draw [->,visible on=<5->] ()
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Your document doesn't compile, since the `\pk` command is undefined.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, just updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows,
    calc,
    chains,
    decorations,
    decorations.text,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    matrix,
    positioning,
    shapes,
    tikzmark
}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Protocol View}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (e0) at (0,0) {$E_0$};
    \node (epk) at (6,0) {$E_{pk}$};
    \path[->] (e0) edge node[auto]{$\mathfrak{s}$} (epk);
    \uncover<2->{
      \node (er) at (3,3) {$E_r$};
      \path[->] (e0) edge node[auto]{$\mathfrak{r}$} (er);
    }
    \uncover<4->{
      \path[dashed,->] (epk) edge node[auto,swap]{$\mathfrak{r}\cdot\mathfrak{s}^{-1}$} (er);
      \node (b0) at (0,3) {$b = 0$};
      \node (b1) at (6,3) {$b = 1$};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm]
        % nodes
        \node[alice,minimum size=1cm,] (s) at (0,0) {Alice};
        \node[bob,minimum size=1cm,right of=s] (r) {Bob};
        % paths
        \draw [->,visible on=<2->] (r) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center] {$E_r$} (s);
        \draw [->,visible on=<4->] ($(s.east)+(1em,-1.3em)$) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,align=center,above] {$0$ or $1$} ($(r.west)+(-1em,-1.3em)$);
        \draw [->,visible on=<4->] ($(s.east)+(1em,-2.8em)$) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,align=center,above] {$0$ or $1$} ($(r.west)+(-1em,-2.8em)$);
        %\draw [->,visible on=<5->] ()
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What I did was to leave a blank line between the pictures and to add the option `below` to the node that creates “0 or 1”.

Comment: First part is fine, but the second part is not exactly what I want. I want to draw one more line from Bob to Alice, there should be 3 lines, and putting "0 or 1" as below is not as useful for me. So, there should be 3 lines, and all of them should have their text written above.

Comment: Also putting just an empty line pushes everything to the left of the slide, they are not in the middle of the slide.

Comment: The first one is easy to solve: put everything in a `\begin{center}...\end{center}` environment.

Comment: I've edited my answer.